# can google maps show KML custom icons at any zoom level?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a KML file that defines custom icons. The custom icons will all show up if I zoom in but when I zoom out some get converted into the default Blue marker. It seems to happen where icons group together.

Is google maps replacing multiple markers by a simpler default marker?

Is there a way for the KML to tell google maps to use the custom icons at any zoom level?